# Change background color of community cloud page / experience builder

Tags: customer-community, community-cloud, experience-builder-page

I'm trying to change the background color of the community cloud default standard pages (in Customer Service template).  Managed to change most of the colors including the background color of the whole page but the "white color" in the middle section of the page isn't changing.
[image]

Using the page background color option available below, I changed the color to sand color. You can see the sand background color only reflects around the main content. The "white" background color in the centre section remains as is.  Is there no option to change the background color of this main middle section?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the navigation path on the standard Customer Service template community so I can try to reproduce the behaviour for the main middle section you are referring

Comment: Thanks. It will be in Setup > All Sites > New. It will open Site wizard to "Choose the Experience You Love" (Customer Service) @Swetha

Comment: Well, I mean what is the name of the component of the "main middle section" you were referring to :) I have tried with "RecordList" Component that is shown on clicking the "case" tab and see that the background isn't changing and remains white.Please confirm if you are also seeing the same and that is what you are trying to fix?

Comment: I have figured out how to do it.  Using Custom CSS I managed to do it.  It isn't component that I dragged and dropped.  It is the standard default component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Brand Builder > Themes > Edit CSS, I figured out there's an option to overwrite the style of any component.

Though the middle section is not a component at all, I did inspect using Chrome to find the "class" of the middle sections.  It is '`siteforceContentArea`' div in '`cCenterPanel`' td.  I have added the background color that I needed in the Edit CSS section for this div by overriding the class.

[image]

More on overriding the templates with custom CSS here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm